# Dictionary with “b”: "\u0001", not able to convert

Tags: swift, character

with this values in dictionary : “b”: "\u0001", “s”: "\u0000" I am not able to get the expected output of b = 1, s = 0
I have tried this following also checked couple of questions but with no success I am posting here.

```
  appObj.b = appdict[“b”]! as! String //= "\u{01}" 
  appObj.s = appdict[“s”]! as! String //= "\0"
  print(appdict[“b”]! as? Character) //= nil
  print(appdict[“s”]! as? Character) //= nil
```

Thank you

Comment: there is a difference in double quotes: your case - “, normal double quotes - ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `\u{...}` escape sequences represent Unicode scalars. It seems like you want to get the number inside the `{}`.

To do this, just access `.unicodeScalars.first!.value`:

```
"\u{0000}".unicodeScalars.first!.value // 0
```

In your case:

```
print(appdict[“b”]!.unicodeScalars.first!.value)
```